# JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type -- for an external object

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I have an object called `GeoJsonPoint` from spring framework, and it can't get deserialized by jackson mapper in my integration test. Additionally, I can't add a dummy constructor because it is an external object. So I am stuck. This is my main entity;

```
@Document(collection = "foodTrucks")
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
public class FoodTruckEntity {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String applicant;
    private Status status;
    private String[] foodItems;
    private Double longitude;
    private Double latitude;
    private GeoJsonPoint geoJsonPoint;

    public FoodTruckEntity() {};

    // getters and setters
}
```

And the test

```
@Test
public void test() {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
    Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

    String getNearFoodTrucksUrl = "http://localhost:8080/food-truck/near-locations/longitude/-122.398658184604/latitude/37.7901490737255/findAll";
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(getNearFoodTrucksUrl);
    ClientResponse response = webResource.get(ClientResponse.class);
    GeoResults<FoodTruckEntity> geoResults = webResource.get(new GenericType<GeoResults<FoodTruckEntity>>(){});

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new WebApplicationException();
    }
}
```

And the error I get;

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.data.geo.GeoResults<entity.FoodTruckEntity>]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@107ed6fc; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:644)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:604)
```

EDIT: This is the dependencies for jersey I have

```
<!-- JERSEY JSON -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- JERSEY JSON -->
```

EDIT_2: Response as a String looks like this,

```
{
   "averageDistance":{
      "value":0.0,
      "metric":"MILES",
      "normalizedValue":0.0,
      "unit":"mi"
   },
   "content":[
      {
         "content":{
            "id":{
               "timestamp":1429498845,
               "machineIdentifier":11487078,
               "processIdentifier":1432,
               "counter":9275496,
               "time":1429498845000,
               "date":1429498845000,
               "timeSecond":1429498845
            },
            "applicant":"Cupkates Bakery, LLC",
            "facilityType":"Truck",
            "status":"APPROVED",
            "foodItems":[
               "Cupcakes"
            ],
            "longitude":-122.398658184604,
            "latitude":37.7901490737255,
            "geoJsonPoint":{
               "x":-122.398658184604,
               "y":37.7901490737255,
               "type":"Point",
               "coordinates":[
                  -122.398658184604,
                  37.7901490737255
               ]
            }
         },
         "distance":{
            "value":0.0,
            "metric":"MILES",
            "normalizedValue":0.0,
            "unit":"mi"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I've never used this GeoResults API . Can you post the String result `webresource.get(String.class)`. I'm curious what the JSON looks like.

Comment: @peeskillet Sure. I have posted the very simple response as a string in my question.

Comment: @peeskillet I have posted the very simple response as a string in my question.

Comment: the constructor of GeoJsonPoint requires x, y values passed to it.  How about defining your own GeoJsonPoint  class and remove the reference to   Spring's GeoJsonPoint

Comment: @faljbour Thanks for your response. I thought that before but I have to use GeoJsonPoint while making a query into db. So, I have to mess up with backend. I will try to parse the result as a string which seems a considerable alternative.

Comment: Note that the error does not complain about GeoJsonPoint. It complains about GeoResults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if you look at all the classes from the [`org.springframework.data.geo`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/geo), you will notice that pretty much all the classes don't have a no-arg constructor, which the default behavior of the `ObjectMapper` needs to deserialize POJOs from JSON.

One way to get around this with third-party APIs, is to make use of [Jackson Mixins](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations). If you look at the [`GeoModule`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/geo/GeoModule.java), this is a module you can register with the `ObjectMapper`, that includes some Mixins

```
mapper.registerModule(new GeoModule());
```

If you look at the [`org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/geo/GeoJsonModule.java), you will another module [`GeoJsonModule`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/geo/GeoJsonModule.java) that has some included Mixins also. This module should take care of the `GeoJsonPoint`.

But the main problem for your use case, is (if you look back at the `GeoModule`) is that there is no Mixin for the `GeoResult` or `GeoResults`, which you need to parse the JSON.

I made a module to take care of the `GeoResult` but the `GeoResults` doesn't work at the moment.

```
public class GeoModuleExt extends SimpleModule {

    public GeoModuleExt() {
        super("Mixins", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
        setMixInAnnotation(GeoResult.class, GeoResultMixin.class);
        setMixInAnnotation(GeoResults.class, GeoResultsMixin.class);
    }
    
    static abstract class GeoResultMixin {
        GeoResultMixin(@JsonProperty("content") Object content, 
                       @JsonProperty("distance") Distance distance) {    
        }
    }
    
    static abstract class GeoResultsMixin {
        GeoResultsMixin(@JsonProperty("results")List<GeoResult> results) {
           
        }   
    }
}
```

You can play around with it. I don't have time right now to work on it (hence the half-@$$ solution), but when I get some time, if you haven't figured it out, I'll see what I can do.

As a test, you can use the `ObjectMapper` in a standalone, to make sure it works first

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new GeoJsonModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new GeoModule());
        // Our custom module
        mapper.registerModule(new GeoModuleExt());

        // Create FoodTruckEntity - 
        GeoJsonPoint geoJsonPoint = new GeoJsonPoint(10, 10);
        FoodTruckEntity foodTruck = new FoodTruckEntity();
        // set all properties fro foodTruck

        // Create GeoResult
        GeoResult<FoodTruckEntity> geoResult
                = new GeoResult<FoodTruckEntity>(foodTruck, new Distance(10,
                                                 Metrics.KILOMETERS));
        
        // Serialize geoResult
        String geoResultString = mapper.writeValueAsString(geoResult);
        System.out.println(geoResultString);
        
        JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(
                GeoResult.class, FoodTruckEntity.class);
        
        // Deserialize geoResultString
        GeoResult<FoodTruckEntity> parsedGeoResult 
                = mapper.readValue(geoResultString, type);
        System.out.println(parsedGeoResult.getDistance());
        System.out.println(parsedGeoResult.getContent().getApplicant());
        
        // Up to this point everything is fine. It's the deserialization of
        // `GeoResults` thats a problem.
        
        /*
        List<GeoResult> results = new ArrayList<GeoResult>();
        results.add(geoResult);
        results.add(geoResult);
        GeoResults geoResults = new GeoResults(results);
        
        String resultsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(geoResults);
        System.out.println(resultsString);
        
        
        JavaType resultType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(
                                       GeoResults.class, FoodTruckEntity.class);
        
        GeoResults<FoodTruckEntity> parsedGeoResults 
                            = mapper.readValue(resultsString, resultType);
        for (GeoResult<FoodTruckEntity> gr: parsedGeoResults) {
            System.out.println(gr.getContent().getGeoJsonPoint());
        }*/
    }
}
```

When you get the test to work, you can register the `ObjectMapper` with Jersey like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new GeoJsonModule());
mapper.registerModule(new GeoModule());
// Our custom module
mapper.registerModule(new GeoModuleExt());

ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getSingletons().add(new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper));
Client client = Client.create(config);
```

---

### UPDATE

So after some playing around, I was able to get it to work with this Mixin for the `GeoResults`. Just update the above `GeoModuleExt`

```
static abstract class GeoResultsMixin {
    GeoResultsMixin(@JsonProperty("results") List<GeoResult> results, 
                    @JsonProperty("averageDistance") Distance averageDistance) {
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("results")
    abstract List<GeoResult> getContent(); 
}
```

It works as expected with the above test. Haven't tested yet with Jersey, but if it works with the `ObjectMapper`, it shouldn't be a problem with Jersey, as long as we have configured the Jackson provider to use the mapper.

Comment: Oh my god this is a perfect solution. I am struggling right now but I got the idea. I didnt know that there was an API called Mixins. Thanks a lot for providing a great solution!

Comment: It's odd. In my test, the array property in `GeoResults` shows in JSON as `results`. But in your post, it shows as `content`. I think that may be the problem. Let me look into it when I get some time later

Comment: I guess I have to create a mixin for `content` object. I post the error into here. http://pastebin.com/b4ThJNmZ. By the way, you are using `com.faster.xml` dependencies right ? `

Comment: No, I am using the `org.codehaus` that comes with the `jersey-json` dependency. Try to change the `results` in my mixin to `content` and see what happens. I don't have my IDE open right now

Comment: I think because the `getContent` method I override the property, so when I serialize the result will be `results` but without adding the mixin, the results will be `content` based on the name of the getter.

Comment: actually when I try the org.codehaus version `objectMapper` doesnt accept `GeoModule`

Comment: Ah, you know what I did, I actually copy and pasted the code from the Guthub. I didn't use the actual dependency. I guess the project uses Jackson 2. So the `SimpleModule` _is_ Jackson 2. Yeah, you should use the Jackson 2. You will need to add the dependency. Just use [this one](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider). The configuration shouldn't be any different, as this also has `JacksonJsonProvider`

Comment: oh yeah I was using `com.faster.xml` version. I just asked to be sure. You meant say change `@JsonProperty("results")` to `@JsonProperty("content")` right ?

Comment: nope. Nothing changed. this is the same error with before `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "unit" (class org.springframework.data.geo.Distance), not marked as ignorable `

Comment: Let me take a look at it. Give me a minute.

Comment: So I'm looking at the different versions of the `GeoModule`, and it looks like for the `DistanceMixin`, the `unit` property isn't set as ignorable until the latest `spring-data-common-1.10.0.RELEASE` But after fixing that, you have a problem with the Mongo ObjectId.

Comment: You might want to look at different posts about how to handle the Mongo ObjectId. There seems to be a few different solutions I was able to find

Comment: Nevermind. I guess I will change the data type (create my own) which looks much easier to keep and test. By the way, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No prob. Also if you are stuck with using the lower version of Spring data, you can copy the [mixin in the newer version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/1.10.0.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/geo/GeoModule.java#L51), and just add it to your module. From what I've tested, it should work, aside from the ObjectId problem. I commented out the `ObjectId` related stuff and deleted it from the JSON, and everything works