# JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode]

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have read [JSONMappingException for External Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737093/jsonmappingexception-no-suitable-constructor-found-for-type-for-an-external) , [JSONMappingException for Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625783/jsonmappingexception-no-suitable-constructor-found-for-type-simple-type-class)  but can't found solution for `ObjectNode` class.

By Reading [JSONMappingException for External Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737093/jsonmappingexception-no-suitable-constructor-found-for-type-for-an-external) 
I understand that you have to register Object in mapper but I have not created any ObjectMapper class as I am calling web service

```
mapper.registerModule(new GeoModule());
```

I am trying to call web service of My POJO (`ReportQueryData.java`) which contain `ObjectNode` (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode) instance variable.

**ReportQueryData.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class ReportQueryData {
    private ObjectNode parentsData;

    public ObjectNode getParentsData() {
        return parentsData;
    }

    public void setParentsData(ObjectNode parentsData) {
        this.parentsData = parentsData;
    }
}
```

Now I am calling web service containing ReportQueryData in request and I am facing below exception

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]  at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@3da45801; line: 1, column: 155] (through reference chain: com.atlassian.qtm.model.ReportQueryData["parentsData"])
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializer.java:740)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:683)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write default constructor for this class also like this

```
public ReportQueryData (){

}
```

**Edit:** : try to wrap that class in your and use your class.

```
 class A{

    A(String s){

    }
}

class B extends A{

    B(){
        super("str");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not declared any constructor in ReportQueryData so by default compiler provides me default constructor.  I am facing issue in ObjectNode as ObjectNode does not have default constructor

Comment: hmm, So in that class default constructor have to be there because it calls from reflection API of java. If that is not your class then write your own and extends it from `ObjectNode` and use that one

Comment: See my Edit for that what i have suggest